# Write a program to find the sum of positive odd numbers and the product of positive even numbers less than or equal to 30

Tags: c, types, int

I am having some problems with writing a C program for this question. Maybe am reading the question wrong and doing it the wrong way. Could someone help me with it please? This is they way I'm trying to do it

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
    int j, sum=0;
    long int product=1;
    for(j=1;j<=30;j=j+2)
    {
        sum=sum+j;
    }
    for(j=2;j<=30;j=j+2)
    {
        product=product*j;
    }
    printf("\nThe sum of positive odd numbers is: %d", sum);
    printf("\nThe product of positive even numbers is: %d", product);
}
```

The output I am getting is:

```
The sum of positive odd numbers is: 225
The product of positive even numbers is: -1409286144
```

I am getting the product part wrong. I have tried using unsigned long int, long long, unsigned long long. Nothing works.

Comment: Your product is overflowing the limits of your storage type. Try swapping up from a `long int` to a bigger storage type.

Comment: 2*4*8...*28 gives roughly a 30 digit number. You'll pretty much need a floating point type to hold that. For what it's worth: the sum of N consecutive odd numbers (starting from 1) gives N squared, so you can compute that part a little more quickly and easily.

Comment: Use modulo instead to condense your code to 1 loop. pseudocode- for (j=1,j<=30,j++)  If j%2=0, then product=product*j, else sum=sum+j

Comment: Your answer should just fit within a 64-bit integer number.

Comment: Gah can't delete comments and StackOverflow URL parser is broken

Comment: The sheer size of this simple product is a gentle reminder that we should live in fear of algorithms that have factorial time complexity!! =)

Comment: `main` returns `int`, not `void`. Whoever or whatever told you to use `void main(void)` probably doesn't know C very well. Beware.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: No standard floating point type can hold that result; IEEE double only has 52 bits of precision.

Comment: @R..: Right -- none of them is going to hold it to full precision, but at least they can represent some number near 1e30 without overflowing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `%ld` instead of `%d` in your `printf`:

`printf("\nThe product of positive even numbers is: %ld", product);`

Since it's a `long int` and not an `int`.

If you use `long long int`, you'd want `%lld`. You might need the long long size, given that this is a very very large product. I don't know if your platform's `long int` is 32 or 64 bit, but you will certainly need a 64 bit number here.

The `long long` format string can vary depending on your exact platform and compiler, but mostly things have standardized on `%lld` nowadays. In particular, old Microsoft compilers sometimes used `%I64d`.

Comment: @StilesCrisis I am afraid `%ld` in `printf()` produces an incorrect output (negative number) both in my compiler Mingw and `ideone`   http://ideone.com/GRSMLE

Comment: @SheerFish: you are in 32 bit mode, and that is overflow you are seeing. On a 32 bit platform, to get the correct result you must use `long long int`.

Answer (score 1):

There are no issues as far as the sum of all odd numbers less than 30 is concerned as it's only `225`.But the product of all even numbers (or odd numbers for that matter) less than 30 is an **enormous** number.For that you need a data type with larger capacity.In the following program I have simply used `double` instead of `long int` for `product` and I have used the `%e` format specifier to display the product in `prinf()` in a neat way, though you can use `%f` as well.

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main(void)    //Return type of main() is "int",not "void" as you've used
{
    int j, sum=0;
    double product=1;   //Change type of "product" to "double"

    for(j=1;j<=30;j=j+2)
    {
        sum=sum+j;
    }
    for(j=2;j<=30;j=j+2)
    {
        product=product*j;
    }

    printf("The sum of positive odd numbers is: %d\n", sum); 
    printf("The product of positive even numbers is: %e",product); //Use %e 
}
```

**Output** 
           `The sum of positive odd numbers is: 225`

```
       The product of positive even numbers is: 4.284987e+16
```

Comment: @RaedShahid Did `%ld` in `printf()` solve your problem as per the poster above suggested?It  found incorrect result in it.   http://ideone.com/GRSMLE

Comment: `double` may provide a close approximation but is unlikely to get the actual correct answer. Depending on your needs it may be sufficient. `long long int` will be precise but will also start failing when the result grows > 2^64, while the `double` will continue to work just with decreased precision.

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture not really. it does give incorrect result so i had to use `long long int`.

Comment: @RaedShahid `long long int` gives correct result on my 32 bit system,but there is overflow for `long int`.So StilesCrisis is right,it's just that `long int` is not enough in a 32 bit system like mine.

Answer (score -1):

**calculate use unsinged int (32bit)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef unsigned short UInt16;
typedef unsigned UInt32;
typedef struct _unums {
    size_t size;
    UInt16 *nums;//array 
} UNums;

void UNums_init(UNums *num, UInt16 n){
    num->nums = malloc(sizeof(UInt16));
    num->nums[0] = n;
    num->size = 1;
}

void UNums_mul(UNums *num, UInt16 n){
    UInt16 carry = 0;
    size_t i;

    for(i=0;i<num->size;++i){
        UInt32 wk = n;
        wk = wk * num->nums[i] + carry;
        num->nums[i] = wk % 10000;
        carry = wk / 10000;
    }
    if(carry){
        num->size += 1;
        num->nums = realloc(num->nums, num->size * sizeof(UInt16));
        num->nums[i] = carry;
    }
}

void UNums_print(UNums *num){
    size_t i = num->size;
    int w = 0;
    do{
        --i;
        printf("%0*hu", w, num->nums[i]);
        if(!w) w = 4;
    }while(i!=0);
}

void UNum_drop(UNums *num){
    free(num->nums);
    num->nums = NULL;
}

int main( void ){
    UNums n;
    UInt16 i;
    assert(sizeof(UInt32) == 4);//32bit
    assert(sizeof(UInt16) == 2);//16bit

    UNums_init(&n, 1);
    for(i=2;i<=30;i+=2)
        UNums_mul(&n, i);
    UNums_print(&n);//42849873690624000
    UNum_drop(&n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: reason for downvote What is? Please tell me if there is a mistake in the program.

Comment: its not me. but i didn't understand what you have done here and i'm pretty novice in C as you can tell by the question i have asked :p

Comment: Okey-dokey
Have you ever the calculation by writing the multiplication?